# How to switch from Long to Wide format table in R

Tags: r

I am trying to change my data from wide to long format.

It currently looks like this:
[image]

And I would like it to look like:

[image]

This is my current code but does not seem to be working:

`gather(parishpop, key= “New_var_name”, value= “var_value”, X2002, X2003, X2004, X2005, X2006, X2007, X2008, X2009, X2010, X2011, X2012, X2013, X2014, X2015, X2016, X2017, X2018, X2019, X2020)`

Comment: You could try tidyr::pivot_longer()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: A better version using `dplyr` and `tidyr` only:

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -Parish,
    names_to = "Year",
    values_to = "Population",
    names_pattern = 'X(\\d+)',
    names_transform = list(Year = as.integer))
  )
```

```
  Parish  Year Population
   <chr>  <int>      <int>
 1 Acadia  2002      59244
 2 Acadia  2003      59541
 3 Acadia  2004      59839
 4 Acadia  2005      60138
 5 Acadia  2006      58697
 6 Acadia  2007      59958
 7 Acadia  2008      62194
 8 Acadia  2009      63015
 9 Acadia  2010      61877
10 Acadia  2011      61865
# ... with 134 more rows
```

First answer:
We could first `pivot_longer` then remove the `X` in Year. Here we have used `parse_number` from `readr` package which I personally use often!

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -Parish,
    names_to = "Year",
    values_to = "Population"
  ) %>% 
  mutate(Year = parse_number(Year))
```

```
 Parish  Year Population
   <chr>  <dbl>      <int>
 1 Acadia  2002      59244
 2 Acadia  2003      59541
 3 Acadia  2004      59839
 4 Acadia  2005      60138
 5 Acadia  2006      58697
 6 Acadia  2007      59958
 7 Acadia  2008      62194
 8 Acadia  2009      63015
 9 Acadia  2010      61877
10 Acadia  2011      61865
# ... with 134 more rows
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(Parish = c("Acadia", "Allen", "Ascension", "Assumption", 
"Avoyelles", "Beauregard", "Bienville", "Bossier", "Caddo"), 
    X2002 = c(59244L, 24552L, 71862L, 23479L, 41889L, 32655L, 
    16253L, 95247L, 249944L), X2003 = c(59541L, 24675L, 72222L, 
    23596L, 42099L, 32819L, 16334L, 95724L, 251195L), X2004 = c(59839L, 
    24798L, 72583L, 23714L, 42310L, 32983L, 16416L, 96203L, 252452L
    ), X2005 = c(60138L, 24922L, 72946L, 23833L, 42521L, 33148L, 
    16498L, 96684L, 253715L), X2006 = c(58697L, 21435L, 94128L, 
    23361L, 41954L, 33009L, 15626L, 101918L, 254092L), X2007 = c(59958L, 
    25524L, 99056L, 22991L, 42169L, 34776L, 14907L, 108705L, 
    252609L), X2008 = c(62194L, 26178L, 100132L, 24146L, 43889L, 
    36139L, 15604L, 110352L, 260391L), X2009 = c(63015L, 26523L, 
    101453L, 24465L, 44468L, 36616L, 15810L, 111808L, 263826L
    ), X2010 = c(61877L, 25702L, 107890L, 23333L, 42106L, 35831L, 
    14306L, 117675L, 255590L), X2011 = c(61865L, 25740L, 110075L, 
    23185L, 41795L, 36090L, 14261L, 120134L, 256967L), X2012 = c(61997L, 
    25622L, 112218L, 23072L, 41572L, 36333L, 14192L, 123160L, 
    257252L), X2013 = c(62299L, 25664L, 114636L, 23199L, 41275L, 
    36260L, 13961L, 124021L, 255127L), X2014 = c(62667L, 25714L, 
    117282L, 23047L, 41088L, 36239L, 13782L, 124868L, 252605L
    ), X2015 = c(62679L, 25631L, 119374L, 22898L, 40979L, 36531L, 
    13823L, 125554L, 251345L), X2016 = c(62786L, 25680L, 121558L, 
    22756L, 40983L, 36973L, 13780L, 125920L, 248837L), X2017 = c(62559L, 
    25583L, 123177L, 22568L, 40836L, 36847L, 13631L, 126959L, 
    245935L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

# wide to long
melt(df
     , id.vars = "i..Parish"
     , measure.vars = patterns("^X")
     , variable.name = 'Year'
     , value.name = "Population"
     )[, Year := gsub('X', '', Year)][]
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! Do you know if there is a way to get rid of the X's once my data is is in the long version.

Comment: Hi. Updated solution to name column `Year` and rid `X`s

Comment: @SweepyDodo An alternative to using `gsub` would be to put `[, Year := parse_number(as.character(Year))][]` after the closing parenthesis from `melt`.

Comment: @AndrewGillreath-Brown. How ru.
Yes, u r very right. Tho I would like to load up as few packages as possible. Still, am going to implement the chaining. Thank u!